# 64 bit mask, why do these produce different results?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to understand why `bitMaskB` is incorrect. It works with every number except for `bitLength = 64`. The reason I have it this way instead of `(1 << bitLength) - 1` is to support `bitLength = 64` without overflowing the `unsigned long long int`.

```
unsigned long long bitMaskA = ((1 << (bitLength - 1)) - 1)
                             + (1 << (bitLength - 1));

unsigned long long bitMaskB = 1 << (bitLength - 1);
                   bitMaskB = (bitMaskB - 1) + bitMaskB;

std::cout << bitMaskB           << std::endl; // 18446744069414584319
std::cout << bitMaskA           << std::endl; // 18446744073709551615
std::cout << 0xffffffffffffffff << std::endl; // 18446744073709551615
```

UPDATE:

I fixed the problem by doing `(bitMaskB - 1) | bitMaskB` instead, but I would still like to know why this happens.

Comment: You might want to try `1ULL` instead of `1`.

Comment: Can you print the results in hex please, I have no idea what I'm looking at.

Comment: what's wrong with overflowing the unsigned long long int?

Comment: @Ap31 bitMask = (1 << bitLength) - 1 produces 0 at bitLength = 64.

Comment: @njuffa that works. thank you. I guess my compiler automatically converted in A but not B.

Comment: What values you expect to get?

Comment: @Kyy13 [shifting more than the width of the type invokes UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270492/995714), so all bets are off

Comment: What is `bitLength` defined as?

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates: [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714), [Why doesn't left bit-shift, "<<", for 32-bit integers work as expected when used more than 32 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7401888/995714), [Bitwise Leftshift (<<) strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16879251/995714), [Bitwise shift in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46769196/995714)

Comment: @phuclv My question is not a duplicate of those questions, because I am not shifting by more than the width of the type. unsigned long long = (1 << 63) + ( (1 << 63) - 1) where the width if the type is 64 bits long.

Comment: @Kyy13 read those questions carefully. `1 << 63` shifts more than the type's width unless you're on a platform with 64-bit (or wider) int, because [1 is an `int` literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23858905/995714). Did you see njuffa's comment above? Some other duplicates: [printf 64bit type specifier issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16415691/995714), [Compute signed long max value in C using bit shift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41418472/995714)